# Jackson multiple abstract Objet serialisation

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I have a problem when i want deserialize the object "ObjectAbstract1". I have this error :

I tried several solutions but without success ... If someone has an idea? The problem is located on object ObjectAbstract2 but I do not see what jackson anotation to add

```
-- serializing --
{"object1Type":"INSTANCE_OBJECT1","autor":"John","objectAbstract2":{"nameProc":"Processus transfert","identifiant":null,"nomObject3":"Demande de transfert"},"state":"En cours","priority":null}
-- deserializing --
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of fr.test.jakson.ObjectAbstract2, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: {"object1Type":"INSTANCE_OBJECT1","autor":"John","objectAbstract2":{"nameProc":"Processus transfert","identifiant":null,"nomObject3":"Demande de transfert"},"state":"En cours","priority":null}; line: 1, column: 49] (through reference chain: fr.test.jakson.Object1["objectAbstract2"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:892)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:139)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:520)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:95)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:258)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:136)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:122)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:93)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:131)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:42)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3736)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2726)
    at fr.test.jakson.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:33)
```

ObjectAbstract1 :

```
package fr.test.jakson;

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes.Type;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "object1Type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = Object1.class, name = "INSTANCE_OBJECT1") })
public abstract class ObjectAbstract1 implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private String autor;

   private ObjectAbstract2 objectAbstract2;

   public ObjectAbstract1() {
   }

   public String getAutor() {
      return autor;
   }

   public void setAutor(String autor) {
      this.autor = autor;
   }

   public ObjectAbstract2 getObjectAbstract2() {
      return objectAbstract2;
   }

   public void setObjectAbstract2(ObjectAbstract2 objectAbstract2) {
      this.objectAbstract2 = objectAbstract2;
   }

}
```

Object1 :

```
package fr.test.jakson;

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;

@JsonTypeName("INSTANCE_OBJECT1")
public class Object1 extends ObjectAbstract1 implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private String state;
   private String priority;

   public Object1() {

   }

   public String getState() {
      return state;
   }

   public void setState(String state) {
      this.state = state;
   }

   public String getPriority() {
      return priority;
   }

   public void setPriority(String priority) {
      this.priority = priority;
   }

}
```

ObjectAbstract2 :

```
package fr.test.jakson;

import java.io.Serializable;

public abstract class ObjectAbstract2 implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private String nameProc;

   public ObjectAbstract2() {
   }

   public String getNameProc() {
      return nameProc;
   }

   public void setNameProc(String nameProc) {
      this.nameProc = nameProc;
   }

}
```

ObjectAbstract3 :

```
package fr.test.jakson;

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes.Type;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "objectAbstract3Type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = Object3.class, name = "Object3"), @Type(value = Object2.class, name = "Object2") })
public abstract class ObjectAbstract3 extends ObjectAbstract2 implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private String identifiant;

   public ObjectAbstract3() {
   }

   public String getIdentifiant() {
      return identifiant;
   }

   public void setIdentifiant(String identifiant) {
      this.identifiant = identifiant;
   }

}
```

Object2 :

```
package fr.test.jakson;

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;

@JsonTypeName("Object2")
public class Object2 extends ObjectAbstract3 implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private String nomObject2;

   public Object2() {
   }

   public String getNomObject2() {
      return nomObject2;
   }

   public void setNomObject2(String nomObject2) {
      this.nomObject2 = nomObject2;
   }

}
```

Object 3 :

```
package fr.test.jakson;

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;

@JsonTypeName("Object3")
public class Object3 extends ObjectAbstract3 implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private String nomObject3;

   public Object3() {
   }

   public String getNomObject3() {
      return nomObject3;
   }

   public void setNomObject3(String nomObject3) {
      this.nomObject3 = nomObject3;
   }

}
```

Main Class test :

```
package fr.test.jakson;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class MainTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
      Object1 object1 = new Object1();
      object1.setAutor("John");
      object1.setState("En cours");

      Object3 object3 = new Object3();
      object3.setNomObject3("Demande de transfert");

      ObjectAbstract2 objectAbstract2 = (ObjectAbstract2) object3;
      objectAbstract2.setNameProc("Processus transfert");

      ObjectAbstract1 objectAbstract1 = (ObjectAbstract1) object1;
      objectAbstract1.setObjectAbstract2(objectAbstract2);

      System.out.println("-- serializing --");
      ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
      String s = om.writeValueAsString(objectAbstract1);
      System.out.println(s);

      System.out.println("-- deserializing --");
      ObjectAbstract1 instanceTacheDeserializing;
      ObjectMapper om1 = new ObjectMapper();
      String jsonTest = "{\"object1Type\":\"INSTANCE_OBJECT1\",\"autor\":\"John\",\"objectAbstract2\":{\"nameProc\":\"Processus transfert\",\"identifiant\":null,\"nomObject3\":\"Demande de transfert\"},\"state\":\"En cours\",\"priority\":null}";
      instanceTacheDeserializing = om1.readValue(jsonTest, ObjectAbstract1.class);

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ObjectAbstract2 cannot be an Abstract class. Deserializer requires concrete class to convert into java object. Change ObjectAbstract2 class like below

```
package fr.test.jakson;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ObjectAbstract2 implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private String nameProc;

   public ObjectAbstract2() {
   }

   public String getNameProc() {
      return nameProc;
   }

   public void setNameProc(String nameProc) {
      this.nameProc = nameProc;
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for you awnser but in my case i can't change "Abstract class" to a class. Is it possible make a customer Deserializer ?

Comment: Yes extend ObjectAbstract2 into another class. That must be an concrete class like ObjectAbstract2  and use that. Like : ObjectAbstract2Concrete

Comment: I try your solution but it doesn't work because after Jackson don't find attribut "nameProc" of ObjectAbstract2